# Moto-Z Play with TWRP 3.4 asking for password

Tags: twrp

I have an unlocked Moto-Z play.  I able to install 'fastboot flash recovery twrp.img'.  When I boot TWRP, it asks for a password.  I tried "default_password" and I changed my screen lock pin to 1234 and tried that.  both these didn't work.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and took the same steps. Also no effect so I did a full wipe from within TWRP -> cancel on PW page to get in TWRP -> Wipe -> format data -> yes (actually type yes) -> enter -> back -> reboot -> power off -> boot to fastboot (volume down + power button)-> start TWRP.
Now I can use TWRP (without a PW) but you can never boot to android because your system will get encrypted again and you cannot access your data anymore via TWRP.

Have not yet flashed a new rom but I bet I can since the system is no longer encrypted.